# In search of a English word

Tags: single-word-requests, concept

my question is that if a person A does something bad to another person B but regrets it and helps B so that A can forgive himself.....is there any English word to sum up that sentence?

Comment: "Is there any English word that"  ... what?  This question might be better on English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *Is there any English word to sum up that sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Another word would be **atonement**.

When someone **atones** for a wrong, they seek to make amends for their wrondgoing either by offering the wronged person some form of reparation or by undergoing,  themselves, some suffering which is accepted as expiation, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, [***redeem oneself***](http://www.imdb.com/video/user/vi58503193)

> *If you redeem yourself, you make up for wrongs by doing something that makes you seem good again, like when after being irritable and snappy with your grandmother, you redeem yourself by bringing her flowers and apologizing.*
>
> [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/redeem)

Answer (score -1):

Person A is feeling **contrite** towards person B.

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contrite):

> 1. caused by or showing sincere remorse.
> 2. filled with a sense of guilt and the desire for atonement; penitent: a contrite sinner.